# Incluir y quitar campos de un formulario dentro de un modal con jquery

Tags: jquery

voy directo al grano. Tengo un formulario que con unos inputs que son incluidos o excluidos con una funcion de jquery. Mi problemas aparece cuando intento poner ese formulario dentro de um modal, la funcion jquery funciona todo, menos la parte que es para quitar esos inputs.

```
  <button name="Button" href="javascript:void(0);" id="anc_add" type="button" class="round blue ic-add" style="border: none; cursor: pointer; padding: 0.833em; background-position: right center; padding-right: 3em; background-repeat: no-repeat; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;" value="Novo Passageiro" ></button>
  <button name="anc_add"  href="javascript:void(0);" id="anc_rem" type="button" class="round blue ic-delete" style="border: none; cursor: pointer; padding: 0.833em; background-position: right center; padding-right: 3em; background-repeat: no-repeat; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;" value="Remover Último Passageiro" ></button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table width="100%" id="tbl1">
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td width="25%"><div style="width:270px">Informações do Passageiro 01</div></td>
         <td width="25%" style="text-align:center"><input name="passageiros_nome[]" type="text" placeholder="SEU NOME COMPLETO" class="round default-width-input mirror" id="passageiros_nome" style="font-size:12px;" /></td>
         <td width="25%"  style="text-align:center"><input name="passageiros_nascimento[]" type="text" placeholder="SUA DATA DE NASCIMENTO" class="round default-width-input" id="passageiros_nascimento" style="font-size:12px;" /></td>
        <td width="25%"><input name="passageiros_rg[]" type="text" placeholder="SEU NUMERO DO RG / CERTIDAO NASC." class="round default-width-input" id="passageiros_rg" style="font-size:12px;" /></td>
       </tr>

   </tbody>
 </table>


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var cnt = 2;
    $("#anc_add").click(function(){
    $('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr> <td width="25%"><div    style="width:270px">Informações do Passageiro 0'+cnt+'</div></td><td width="25%" style="text-align:center"><input name="passageiros_nome[]" type="text" placeholder="NOME COMPLETO DO PASSAGEIRO" class="round default-width-input" id="simple-input28" style="font-size:12px;" /></td><td width="25%"  style="text-align:center"><input name="passageiros_nascimento[]" type="text" placeholder="DATA DE NASCIMENTO" class="round default-width-input" id="simple-input" style="font-size:12px;" /></td><td width="25%"><input name="passageiros_rg[]" type="text" placeholder="NUMERO DO RG / CERTIDAO NASC." class="round default-width-input" id="simple-input7" style="font-size:12px;" /></td></tr>');
   cnt++;
   });


   **Esta es la parte de la funcion que no funciona dentro del modal**

     $("#anc_rem").click(function(){
     if($('#tbl1 tr').size()>1){
     $('#tbl1 tr:last-child').remove();
     }else{
     alert('E necessario pelo menos um passageiro');
     }
     });


   });




    </script>
```

Comment: Es muy poca la info que nos das e incompleta. Si funciona salvo cuando esta dentro de un modal, te puedo sugerir que revises que no estes ejecutando el javascript que tiene el evento antes de que el elemento exista en el DOM, es lo mas común. Pero sin el resto del código es muy dificil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el metodo size(), fue deprecado, si estas usando jquery 3 o superior no existe mas. https://api.jquery.com/size/

Debes evaluar la propiedad length

```
if($('#tbl1 tr').size()>1) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado pero aun asi sigo con el mismo problema.